# Showing that a question has been answered

Tags: discussion

Does something that can be seen from "outside" a question indicate that an answer has been accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the questions overview those questions with the answer count printed on a green background have been accepted.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but couldn't confirm by looking.  Seemed sometimes yes, sometimes no.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So, all questions with a count of 3 have been accepted?  :-p

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Of course not. Only those with a red ring.

Comment: Hihihihihihihihi (long giggle to beat the char count req)

Comment: Nope, the question is answered only when a picture of this question is posted on the meta. **I would like to say that I am the president of SE network**, so I may be right.